# “SQLDeveloper.app” can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

I am looking to install SQL developer

I downloaded the .app file.

When I try and open it I get

“SQLDeveloper.app” can’t be opened because the identity of the developer cannot be confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

For any application which Gatekeeper doesn't trust, yet you deem to be safe...

Right click the app & Select Open from the menu.

This will leave Gatekeeper in place for other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Allow applications downloaded from > Anywhere

Comment: Poor idea. Removes security which could still be in place for other apps.

Comment: You can also locate the application in Finder and then right click to open it. the dialog changes and is explained in the Gatekeeper FAQ to exempt certain apps: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

Comment: This does not change the nature of the warning.

Comment: This is a valid choice for business users (who use products like SQL developer). Apple has this built in "home computer" bias with its security. That's why it integrates personal user "cloud accounts" that entangle personal cloud data storage and app store purchases into the security. This doesn't work for businesses and business software (like oracle SQL developer). Why entangle business apps and data that the company manages into personal cloud storage that the user pays for? It's a painfully broken use case for those using a Mac at work. Macs are used at work. It's not the 90's anymore!